# Determining number of CPU cores during a Maven build

Tags: maven, maven-failsafe-plugin

I'm currently using the Maven Failsafe Plugin to do forked execution of tests (running multiple in parallel in separate JVMs).

I'm manually setting the **forkCount** variable based on the number of cores my machine has, but I'd like for this to be automatically determined by Maven, allowing me to end up with something like:

```
<forkCount>${system.numCores}</forkCount>
```

Is this possible?

Comment: try `${env.Number_Of_Processors}`

Answer (score 4):

You could try using the `build-helper:cpu-count` plugin

http://www.mojohaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/cpu-count-mojo.html

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>get-cpu-count</id>
        <goals>
          <goal>cpu-count</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <cpuCount>system.numCores</cpuCount>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

That will place the available number of cores into the variable `system.numCores`.

You can also specify a projection factor in the config e.g. `<factor>0.75</factor>` if you want to use a fraction of the available cores. This will adjust the number of cores by the given factor and guarantees to return an integer value of at least 1 i.e. Using a factor Will not reduce the number of calculated cores below 1.

Answer (score 2):

You can resolve the number before on your command line.

Linux: `nproc`
Mac OS: `sysctl -n hw.ncpu`
Windows: `wmic cpu get NumberOfCores, NumberOfLogicalProcessors/Format:List` or use environment variable `NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS` (use with `${env.NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS}`)

Note - for windows, you need to tune the output and get the number.

Then, pass the number as a parameter to maven: `-Dsystem.numCores=$NUM` or
`-Dsystem.numCores=%NUM%`

EDIT: You can also generate a file with the property (maven exec plugin) and then read it with the maven properties plugin. All done during the same build, at different stages

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking for something that I can include in the POM (so that e.g other developers don't have to know about passing in the arg)

Comment: Are you windows or linux?

Comment: You can also generate a file with the property (maven exec plugin) and then read it with the maven properties plugin. All done during the same build, at different stages.

Comment: @Eidad AK - Both operating systems ideally. Generating a file sounds a bit hacky but should work, thanks.